# Using Lion's Recovery HD to restore system files

Tags: osx-lion, mac-mini

I've recently removed Microsoft's Office suite according to the instructions on their web site, and I believe I may have gotten ri of some system files in the process. I hear that I can install OS X on top of my current installation to restore them, but because I have a Mac mini, my only option is to use Lion's recovery mode.

If I use Lion's Recovery HD to reinstall OS X over the existing installation, will I lose my data?

I'm going to be installing Mountain Lion in the upcoming weeks, will the ML installer restore the missing files as well? If it will, I rather just wait for the release.

Comment: ML will restore the missing files. I'd wait if you can.

Comment: An alternative option for you, if you can't wait, is to get the latest Lion update (I think it's 10.7.4) and reinstall that.

Answer (score 1):

If you reinstall OS X, you are going to lose all of your data. It is better to make a backup before you play around with your system when you have very important stuffs in it.

I learnt this lesson recently ;)

If you have enable time machine you can perform recovery from an backup. If you dont have then its a good time to buy an ext HDD (for backup) or time capsule (if you have some extra bucks).

Mountain Lion, hmmm well not sure most probably will fix it as it is an upgrade for lion there is a chance for it to have latest versions of the system files which you have deleted.